# Noether's normalization of $k[x,y,z,t]/(xy-zt,xz-yt)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

> Consider the polynomial  ring $k[x,y,z,t]$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field, and let  $I:=(xy-zt,xz-yt)$. Find a Noether's normalization of $A:=k[x,y,z,t]/I$.

$I=(xy-zt-xz+yt,xy-zt+xz-yt)=((x+t)(y-z),(x-t)(y+z))$ so, as a preliminary observation: $$A=k[x+t,x-t,y+z,y-z]/((x+t)(y-z),(x-t)(y+z)).$$ Since $x+t,x-t,y+z,y-z$ are algebraically independent over $k$, we can substitute them respectively with new variables $a,b,c,d$, and thus write  $A=k[a,b,c,d]/(ad,bc)$. Choose the subalgebra $B:=k[a+d,b+c]/((ad,bc) \cap k[a+d,b+c])$.

First, we need that $B$ is free, i.e. that $(ad,bc) \cap k[a+d,b+c]=0$. Take a polynomial $f\in k[a+d,b+c]$, that  will be  the sum of terms of the form  $\gamma(a+d)^m(b+c)^n$, with $\gamma\in k$; modulo $(ad,bc)$, we can reduce to the sum of $\gamma (a^m+d^m)(b^n+c^n)$. Clearly  this sum is equal to  $0$  modulo $(ad,bc)$ only if it is $0$ in $k[a,b,c,d]$, and so only if the initial $f=0$.

Plus $A$ is finite  as a $B$-module: it is generated by (the residues of) $1,a,b,c,d,ab,ac,bd,cd$. For every  $n\ge 1$, $a^n$ or $d^n$ in $A$ are obtained respectively as $(a+d)^{n-1}a$ or $(a+d)^{n-1}d$, and for the powers of $b$ and $c$ holds an analogous argument, using $b+c$. But we can recover also the powers of $ab,ac,bd,cd$; in fact $\beta:=(a+d)(b+c)=ab+ac+bd+cd\in B$, so $a^nb^n=\beta^{n-1}ab$, and similarly for the other three cases.

Going  back to the old variables, $B=k[x+t+y-z,x-t+y+z]/(I\cap k[x+t+y-z,x-t+y+z])$,  that is actually a free subalgebra  for $I\cap k[x+t+y-z,x-t+y+z]=0$. Do you think  my solution is  correct? Working with substitutions and quotients of polynomial rings still confuses me; in particular, I'm less convinced of the first two paragraphs. Thanks in advance